# eclipse tomcate configuration on galileo

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, configuration

I can't configure tomcat 7.0.11 in Eclipse GALILEO. I can't get sever option into it.
Is it an Eclipse problem or what? I can't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse go to Window-> Preference-> Servers then if there is a server already added remove that and add new server. eventually you will be guided to the steps then select your server version to Tomcat 7 and then show the path to the root folder like /some directoreis/Tomcat 7/

This steps should solve ur problem if not then comment again ..

Wish u very very good luck. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Galileo does not support tomcat 7, since Galileo was released before tomcat 7.  Perhaps you should use Helios, which definitely has tomcat 7 support